# Find out the value of the integral $\int_{-2}^{2} \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find out the value of the integral $$\int_{-2}^{2} \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx$$ where $[x]$ denotes the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) (i.e., $[x]$ is the greatest integer $\le x$.)

My attempt ..... $$\int_{-2}^2 \lfloor x^2 – 1\rfloor dx = 2\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx$$ Because $\lfloor x^2 – 1\rfloor$ is even. $$2\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx =\\ 2\int_0^1 \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx+2\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx +2\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}} \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx + 2\int_{\sqrt{3}}^2 \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor dx$$

But how to evaluate this or am I wrong in the whole assumption?

Comment: By square brackets, do you mean entier function?

Comment: By [x] I mean greatest integer $\le$ x

Comment: Sorry for the bad edits..

Comment: You already have done what is needed...by finding the values of $x$ where the floor function changes it's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is even we have $$ I/2 =\int_0^2[x^2-1]\;dx=$$ $$=\int_0^1-1\;dx+\int_1^\sqrt{2}0\;dx+\int_\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3}1\;dx+\int_\sqrt{3}^22\;dx=...$$
$$=(-1)+0+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+(4-2\sqrt{3})=3-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Can you just elaborate atleast one of your integrations meaning how you obtained -1 or 0 etc.. I know it is naive to ask such a silly question after proceeding  upto this level. But I still ask you this. I haven't ever solved such problem .. It's silly and pity.

Comment: Oh now I get it get it... I get it no need to elaborate.

Comment: Of course, for each $x\in [0,1)$ we have $f(x)=-1$

Comment: I have solved it myself.Thanks. I understood what it is for the first case -1 comes because from 0 to 1 f(x) is always -1. You just have to put a value between 0 to 1